# how to return only a particular json object value in angularjs with $http service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like to retrieve particular value in json object and assign it to a variable. Here, i want to assign returned languages value to a array variable. How to do this?

```
$http.get("http://localhost:81/Lhrms/public/languagesService").success(function(data){

   deferred.resolve(data);

});
    return deferred.promise;
```

Following Data is returned:

```
[{"id":"39","languages":"test","created_at":"2014-06-12 10:29:17.000","created_by":"1","updated_at":"2014-06-12 10:29:17.000","updated_by":"1","is_active":"1"},{"id":"38","languages":"test","created_at":"2014-06-12 10:29:17.000","created_by":"1","updated_at":"2014-06-12 10:29:17.000","updated_by":"1","is_active":"1"}];
```

How can I return only the languages from the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't make it?

```
return $http.get("Api/Controller/GetLanguages")
                .then(function(results) {
                     return results.data.languages;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use underscore.js and function pluck

```
$http.get("http://localhost:81/Lhrms/public/languagesService").success(function(data){
var languages = _.pluck(data, 'languages') ;
   deferred.resolve(languages );

});
    return deferred.promise;
```

or you can iterate through thru your result and create new array from languages

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:81/Lhrms/public/languagesService").success(function(data){
    var languages =[];

    angular.forEach(data, function(value){
       languages.push(value.languages);
    }
       deferred.resolve(languages );

    });
        return deferred.promise;
```